# Search contacts upto multiple levels

Tags: mysql, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL recursive tree search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725914/mysql-recursive-tree-search)

I 'm putting a contacts searching option, so user would be able to search contacts upto 10 levels like, I can search a contact of my contact, and contact of his contact and so on upto 10 levels.

It can be done over too many sql joins but I want to know if there is some better solution for it

thanks

Edit:
Here is the schema

User table
id, username

contact table
id, user_id, contact_id

both user_id and contact_id are FK of User table.

Here is the simple query upto 1 level to get my contacts

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN contacts 
ON users.id = contacts.user_id
WHERE users.id = MY_USER_ID
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show show table schema and what queries you are currently running against it.

Comment: I've shown the schema. thanks

Comment: yes u are right, its recursion, but how it will work with this structure. thanks