# how to category list? [PHP accordion]

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, menu

I need to create unlimited categories, and ı use php + mysql.

My database struct.

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronic | 0 |
| 2 | Laptop | 1 |
| 3 | Desktop | 1 |
| 4 | Car | 0 |
| 5 | Renault | 4 |
| 6 | Megane | 5 |

the look i want to achieve ;

[image]

I want to make an accordion menu like this with php but I couldn't find an example, really.

Can you recommend me a method?

Comment: Well, if there wasn't a drop-in solution, how would you imagine you could do it? (Keeping in mind that PHP will just be what puts things in order and HTML/css will be what makes it look like a menu)

Comment: I do not understand you. what exactly did you want to say?

Comment: I am asking you how you think you would do it. That is a good place to start. Logically, how would you approach this? Also, is the navigation just 2 levels deep or deeper?

Comment: Is your questions about retrieving/looping through the information or about how to actually structure the HTML and style it with CSS?

Comment: only 2 levels. The purpose of my asking this question here was to look for a method recommendation for it anyway.

or an example.

I can already do this as pure html/css, the important thing is integration with php.


yes, I'm asking about the php side. 
I couldn't find an example of accordion menu ( BY PHP )

Comment: I was created PHP class to do tasks about nested set. It is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rundiz/nested-set). Please try it on you PC and the recommended example is in [this file](https://github.com/Rundiz/nested-set/blob/version1/tests/via-http/test-list-taxonomy.php). [Screenshot of the result](https://postimg.cc/xcfhNBBG). You have to style it and make it collapsible later.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP part:
Create for example a recursive Function with one parameter.
The parameter is the parentId with 0 as default value.

Inside this function do a Query that selects all entrys where the parent_id is the parameter of the function.

Now do a foreach. inside the foreach call this function but give the id (not the parentid) as parameter and add the result of the subquery to the result of the row as a new column.

In this way you get an array with nesting.

Return this array with nesting.

For showing you basicly do the same again. Create an recursive function that just iterates through the given array and inside the foreach it goes into the next level as parameter you give the subarray.
And then you echo the html code for the current entry.

For styling use bootstrap.

Thats maybe not the most beautiful way, but the short and easy one.

OT:
Keep in mind, that unlimited nesting can be confusing when it has many levels.

What you are looking for is something similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726311/10790010

Comment: Thank you but I guess I didn't explain my problem.

I am able to insert and delete correctly in my tables.

I just want to show it on webpage in 'accordion' menu style.

For this, I wrote my codes above. but I didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Ok, then as first: Are you able to read the Data from the DB and show it in a structured way?

The html structure should be probably a mixture of something like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#using-dropdowns
and this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/

When this step is done, then use something like this
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/
to give it the functionality.

Answer (score -2):

All the code is written in PHP and you can search your databse recursive.

HTML is also generated from PHP with function CreateHtml witch work only with arrays.

You have to insert your databse details
USER = ""
PASSWORD =
HOST = "localhost"
DATABASE = ""

```html
<?php

    function CreateHtmlElements($dom, $insertInto, $array)
    {
        foreach($array as $k=>$v)
        {
            //Use "?tagname" before a tag name
            if (strpos($k, '?') !== false)
            {
                $str = substr($k, 1);
                $elem = $dom->createElement($str, htmlentities($v));
                foreach($array as $k2=>$v2)
                {
                    if ($k2 != "" && strpos($k2, '?') === false)
                    {
                        //extend your array with functions use "fn"
                        if ($k2 == "fn")
                        {
                            foreach($v2 as $v3)
                            {
                                CreateHtmlElements($dom, $elem, $v3());
                            }
                        }
                        else if (!is_array($v2))
                        {
                            $elem->setAttribute($k2, $v2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $insertInto->appendChild($elem);
                $insertInto = $elem;
            }
            if (is_array($v))
            {
                CreateHtmlElements($dom, $insertInto, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    function CreateHtml($array)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
        CreateHtmlElements($dom, $dom, $array);
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
    }


    function DatabaseSearch($parent=0) {
        $USER = "";
        $PASSWORD = ;
        $HOST = "localhost";
        $DATABASE = "";
        
        $CON = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);
    
        $sel ="SELECT * FROM demo WHERE parent_id=$parent";
        $quer = mysqli_query($CON, $sel);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_all($quer, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    }

    function CreateList($row) {
        $a = array();
        foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
            $parent = $v['id'];
            $a[] = array(
                //Header
                array(
                    "?div" => $v['name'],
                    "class" => "accordion",
                    "onclick" => "Accordion();",
                    "style" => "position: relative;",
                ),
                //Accordion Body
                array(
                    "?div" => "",
                    "class" => "panel",
                    "style" => "overflow-x: auto;",
                    CreateList(DatabaseSearch($parent)),
                ),      
            );
        }        
        return $a;
    }

    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
   
    CreateHtml(array(
        "?html" => "",
        "lang" => "en",
        array(
            "?head" => "",
            array(
                "?meta" => "",
                "charset" => "utf-8",
            ),
            array(
                "?meta" => "",
                "name" => "viewport",
                "content" => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0",
            ),
            array(
                "?meta" => "",
                "name" => "keywords",
                "content" => "",
            ),
            array(
                "?meta" => "",
                "name" => "description",
                "content" => "",
            ),
            array(
                "?title" => "Demo",
            ),
            array(
                "?style" => "
                    .accordion {
                        background-color: #eee;
                        color: #444;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        margin-top: 2px;
                        margin-bottom: 2px;
                        padding: 15px;
                        border: none;
                        text-align: left;
                        transition: 0.4s;
                        border-radius: 2px;
                        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
                    }
                    .active, .accordion:hover {
                        background-color: #ccc;
                    }
                    .accordion:after {
                        content: '\\002B';
                        color: #777;
                        float: right;
                        margin-left: 5px;
                    }
                    .active:after {
                        content: '\\2212';
                    }
                    .panel {
                        display: none;
                        padding: 10px;
                        background-color: white;
                        height: 0;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
                        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
                    }                
                ",
                "type" => "text/css",
            ),
        ),
        array(
            "?body" => "",
            array(
                "?script" => "
                    function Accordion() {
                        var target = event.target;
                        target.classList.toggle('active');
                        var panel = target.nextElementSibling;
                        if (panel.style.display == 'block') {
                            panel.style.height = 0;
                            panel.style.display = 'none';
                        } else {
                            panel.style.display = 'block';
                            panel.style.height = '100%';
                        } 
                    }
                ",
            ),
            CreateList(DatabaseSearch()),
        ),
    ));

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Dumping this much code is not an appropriate way to answer questions here.

Comment: I am truly grateful to you. Thank you is little.

Today morning I made a solution in the same way by writing my own algorithm. When I saw your answer in the evening, I realized that the algorithm I wrote was correct. I had it running successfully.

But still, thank you very much.

Comment: The given `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that. Please have a look at prepared statements