# SQL Recursive in Same Table to Find Parent

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

How can I find the parentId of all my items (mySQL)? (there are potentially an infinite amount of levels of hierarchy ... not the best design, but its what I'm working with)

```
ID      PARENTID    NAME
9146    NULL        thing1
9147    NULL        thing2
9148    9146        thing3
9149    9148        thing4
9150    NULL        thing5
9151    9149        thing6
9152    9147        thing7
```

The output should then be:

```
ID     REAL_PARENTID
9146   NULL (or self 9146)
9147   NULL (or self 9147)
9148   9146
9149   9146
9150   NULL (or self 9150)
9151   9146
9152   9147
```

Comment: Do you need to get up to the top parent, or the parent one-up in the hierarchy? Nevermind, I see you need to get to the top.

Comment: The answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704130/recursive-mysql-query should be of use to you.

Comment: Your example is unclear. From the data posted, what you are looking for seems to be *just* SELECT ID, PARENTID from table, that's all. What is the problem ?

Comment: @Marc Not exactly, look at items IDs 9149 and 9151.  The REAL_PARENTID is differnt

Comment: Oh, missed it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @monkey-wrench can you design it such that when any first level child insert occurs, it will find its last ancestor and save it in a `oldest parent` column? That way for any subsequent child insertion, you could just find their immediate parent and copy their `oldest parent` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually scripted tree traversal using MySQL Stored Procedure Programming.

I answered such a question in the [DBA StackExchange back in Oct 24, 2011](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/877). It also included sample data.

Have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using SQL CTE tables (Recursive Queries)

Check this for learning how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: It's mysql... :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Comment: Here is manual for MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/