# How to recursively display comments using twig?

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm rewriting an application using the Silex framework. In this application, users can comment on posts and comments. In the non-MVC application, inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460258/recursive-function-for-comment-and-reply-php-application), I wrote it like this:

```
function display_comments($postid, $parentid=0, $level=0){
   // Get the current comment from DB and display with HTML code
   display_comments($needid, $comment['id'], $level+1);
}
```

However, in the Silex application, I want to retrieve them comment(s) from the database in a repository, send it to a twig-template in the controller and finally display the HTML code in the template. This makes the previous solution incompatible.

What is a good solution for this problem in Silex? What do I put in the view, what in the controller and what in the model?

**EDIT**
I wrote the function in the controller now:

```
$app->get('/needdetail/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $need = $app['need']->findNeed($id);

    function display_comments($app, $needid, $comments=array(), $parentid=0, $level=0){
       $replies = $app['comment']->findByNeed($needid, $parentid);
       foreach($replies as $reply){
            $reply['level'] = $level;
            array_push($comments, $reply);
            display_comments($app, $needid, $comments, $reply['id'], $level+1);
       }
       return $comments;
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('needdetail.html', array('need' => $need, 'comments' => display_comments($app, $id)));
})
```

The level 0 comments are now shown, but a deeper level isn't.

Comment: Get the comment structure recursively from the controller and then pass it to the view to be displayed.

Comment: I tried to do that, but get an "Undefined variable: app" error now...

Comment: Your function is not returning any data

Comment: also pass `$app` as parameter too: `display_comments($app, $id);`

Comment: I'm now returning data and pass $app as a parameter. The level 0 comments are now shown, but a deeper level isn't.

Comment: Try assigning the display_comments return value to $comments in the line below array_push, it becomes $comments = display_comments( $app, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the required result with a slightly different approach. The controller as well as the view contains a recursive function:

**Controller:**

```
$app->get('/needdetail/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
   $need = $app['need']->findNeed($id);

   function get_comments($app, $needid, $parentid=0){
      $comments = array();
      $replies = $app['comment']->findByNeed($needid, $parentid);
      foreach($replies as $comment){
         $comment['replies'] = get_comments($app, $needid, $comment['id']);
         array_push($comments, $comment);    
      }
      return $comments;
   }

   return $app['twig']->render('needdetail.html', array('need' => $need, 'comments' => get_comments($app, $id)));
})
```

**View:**

```
{% for comment in comments %}
   {% include 'comment.html' with {'level': 0} %}            
{% endfor %}
```

**Comment.html:**

```
<div class="comment">
   //Comment HTML
</div>
{% if comment.replies %}
   {%for reply in comment.replies %}
      {% include 'comment.html' with {'comment': reply, 'level': level+1} %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```