# Nested comments with Blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to generate nested comments with Blade in Laravel. It seems as if I have to make a blade template that has unlimited nesting comments preconfigured for each comment and it's child comments. But I want the comments to generate automatically.

This is my Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model {

    protected $table = 'comments';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Post', 'id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

And in my view I'm doing

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
<!-- Comment markup -->
    @if($comment->children->count() > 0)
        @foreach($comment->children as $child)
        <!-- Child comment markup -->
        @if($child->children->count() > 0) // I have to do this unlimited times
            @foreach ....

            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I'm looking for a way to automate this, maybe with a function or something.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460258/recursive-function-for-comment-and-reply-php-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460258/recursive-function-for-comment-and-reply-php-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're basically looking for a recursive view.  This is illustrated in the example below (extracting out the `show` view isn't really needed, but it's a good idea).

*resources/views/comments/index.blade.php*

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    {{-- show the comment markup --}}
    @include('comments.show', ['comment' => $comment])

    @if($comment->children->count() > 0)
        {{-- recursively include this view, passing in the new collection of comments to iterate --}}
        @include('comments.index', ['comments' => $comment->children])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

*resources/views/comments/show.blade.php*

```
<!-- Comment markup -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already figured it out. I wrote a class that generates the markup for given parent id's and their children. It's basically doing what you said, but goes a bit further.

Comment: @ssangki - you should have included your solution as an answer here