# How to use a nested set model for comments system

Tags: mysql

I built a commenting system then realized it is quite clumsy. So I went in search of a better way.

I came across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352543/implementing-recursive-comments-in-php-mysql) which suggested [this page about nested set models](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The idea looks like exactly what I need. However, I have not been able to figure out how this can hold trees for multiple parent comments.

For example, lets say I have a post on my site about eating pizza. Someone comments, then a second user comments, but does not comment on the first comment. This would create 2 trees.

The part that I am not getting is that a nested set model uses left and right node id's. From the searches in the article, it seems the searches could get confused since each tree could have the same values for different left and right nodes.

I'm sure the solution is simple enough. But not so simple that I can get it sorted out.

Comment: So add an additional column that identifies the tree's root?

Comment: You know, that crossed my mind. But I felt there must be some inherent way in nested set models to deal with this.